# Horizontal nested recyclerviews loading weird info in the vertical parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying for a week loading items inside some horizontal recyclerviews contained in one vertical recyclerview(parent). Both need to have endless scrolling the horizontal ones to the right and the vertical while descending.

Right now the endless scrolling and the loading works. However, this is not working correctly because the horizontal ones are loading crazy data from the other children (My guess is that I'm creating the presenters inside the ViewHolder and some how data gets mixed up)

Is there any other way of doing this. That could work better and faster than my approach. Also, some this I can notice the vertical loading is not as smooth as I've seen in some other apps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class EventCatalogAdapter(private val presenter: EventCatalogPresenter):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCatalogAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = presenter.getCategoryEventCount()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
            EventCatalogAdapter.ViewHolder(parent.inflate(R.layout.item_event_catalog), viewType)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) =
            presenter.bind(holder, position)

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = presenter.getItemType(position)

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View, type: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
            EventCatalogItemView, EventViewList, OnItemClickListener<Event>,
            EndlessScrollListener.DataLoader {

        private lateinit var companyId: String
        private lateinit var catId: String
        private val eventPresenter = EventPresenterImpl(this)

        override val titleFormat: String? get() = ""

        init {
            val layoutManager = HorizontalLinearLayoutManager(itemView.context,
                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            itemView.rvEvents.layoutManager = layoutManager
            itemView.rvEvents.addItemDecoration(HorizontalItemDecorator(itemView.context))
            itemView.rvEvents.adapter = EventAdapter(eventPresenter, type, this)
            itemView.rvEvents.addOnScrollListener(EndlessScrollListener(layoutManager, this))
        }

        override fun setTitleVisibility(b: Boolean) {
            itemView.tvCategoryTitle.visibility = if(!b) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun setCategoryTitle(title: String) {
            itemView.tvCategoryTitle.text = title
        }

        override fun eventsByCategory(companyId: String, categoryId: String) {
            this.companyId = companyId
            catId = categoryId
            eventPresenter.getEventsByCategories(companyId, categoryId)
        }

        override fun loadMoreData(totalItems: Int) {
            Log.d("LOAD", "Event presenter: $eventPresenter for category: $catId")
            eventPresenter.getMoreEventsByCategories(companyId, catId, totalItems)
        }

        override fun setActiveEvent(event: Event?) {}

        override fun showSettings() {}

        override fun sendMessage(action: String, bundle: Bundle?) {}

        override fun showStatus(status: Int) {}

        override fun refresh() {
            itemView.rvEvents.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun showMessageTemplate(code: Int) {}

        override fun hideMessageTemplate() {
            refresh()
        }

        override fun onItemClick(item: Event) {

        }

    }

}

class EventAdapter(private val presenter: EventPresenter,
                   private val listener: OnItemClickListener<Event>):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolderItemView>() {

    private var type: Int = EVENT_STANDARD

    constructor(presenter: EventPresenter, type: Int, listener: OnItemClickListener<Event>) :
            this(presenter, listener) {
        this.type = type
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
            ViewHolderItemView(parent.inflate(type))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolderItemView, position: Int) =
            presenter.bind(holder, position)

    override fun getItemCount() = presenter.getCount()

    class ViewHolderItemView(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), EventItemView {

        override fun setEventDate(date: Date?) {
            itemView.tvDate.text = Tools.formatDate(itemView.context, date)
        }

        override fun setName(name: String) {
            itemView.tvName.text = name
        }

        override fun setScannerVisibility(scannerVisibility: Boolean) {
            itemView.ibScanner.visibility = if (scannerVisibility) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
        }

        override fun setEventPoster(posterUrl: String, transformation: Transformation?) {
            Tools.loadImage(posterUrl, itemView.ivPoster, transformation, R.mipmap.portrait_test)
        }

        override fun setTotalRegistrants(totalRegistrants: Long) {
            itemView.tvQtyRegs.text = totalRegistrants.toString()
        }

        override fun addScanAction(event: Event) {
            itemView.ibScanner.setOnClickListener {
                val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                val prefs = PreferenceHelper.customPrefs(itemView.context, auth.currentUser!!.uid)
                prefs.edit().putString(EventInteractorImpl.FIELD_EVENT_ID, event.eventId).apply()
                (itemView.context as SettingsActivity).launchScanner()
            }
        }

        override fun addEventAction(event: Event) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                (itemView.context as SettingsActivity).showRegistrants(event)
            }
        }

    }

}

// Parent items:

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCategoryTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_spacing"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_spacing"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_spacing"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/txt_cat_title" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvEvents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/vertical_spacing"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCategoryTitle" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

// Children items

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/tile_elevation">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPoster"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txt_event_image"
            android:src="@mipmap/portrait_test"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            style="@style/SubTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            tools:text="Washington D.C. " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            style="@style/SubTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            tools:text="03/23" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvQtyRegs"
            style="@style/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            tools:text="140" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ibRegistrants"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txt_registrants"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_registrants_48px"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibScanner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txt_registrants"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_scan_action" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file and your recyclerview adapter class for both horizontal and vertical recyclerviews?

Comment: where did you get data  into recycleview? From api ?

Comment: @Harshai I'm getting my data from a Cloud Firestore Instance directly